# Difference between "Thanks" and "Thank You"

Tags: meaning, word-difference

What is any difference between **Thanks** and **Thank you**?
Are they both same in all aspects?

Comment: Thanks is usually more colloquial, and thank you is usually more formal. However, that isn't to say that thanks can't be used in a formal environment and thank you in a colloquial enviroment.

Comment: @OldBunny2800 Thanks for telling me the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @OldBunny:

> **Thanks** is usually more colloquial, and **thank you** is usually more formal. However, that isn't to say that **thanks** can't be used in a formal environment and **thank you** in a colloquial enviroment.